# What are the rules of cacheControling responses using apollo engine (using cache hints)?

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-server

I'm studying [response caching](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/engine/caching.html) and curious to know about the proper ways of `response caching`.

Even though there are only 2 types of [cache hints](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/engine/caching.html#cache-hints), I don't really have a clear understanding of how to use them properly.

My rule of thumb is that `PRIVATE scope` should be implemented whenever we fetch data that only a logged in user can access.

And I feel completely lost, when it comes to `maxAge`. It seems that there's no difference whether the data will be cashed for 40 sec or 60...

Given an example from Apollo docs, I fail to see the reason behind caching `votes` in `type Post` for 500 seconds and setting caching for `type Post` to 240 (according to the docs: a smaller `maxAge` will override a longer one)

```
type Post @cacheControl(maxAge: 240) {
  id: Int!
  title: String
  author: Author
  votes: Int @cacheControl(maxAge: 500)
  readByCurrentUser: Boolean! @cacheControl(scope: PRIVATE)
}

type Author @cacheControl(maxAge: 60) {
  id: Int
  firstName: String
  lastName: String
  posts: [Post]
}
```

Could you, please, help me understand these concepts as without them it'd be hard to move forward.

Answer (score 2):

You define cache control hints on the schema, and Apollo Engine will then compute the TTL for a response based on the fields included in the query. Given the following schema:

```
type Post @cacheControl(maxAge: 240) {
  id: Int!
  title: String
  author: Author
  votes: Int @cacheControl(maxAge: 30)
  readByCurrentUser: Boolean! @cacheControl(scope: PRIVATE)
}
```

A query for a post will be cacheable for 240 seconds, unless it includes `votes`, which will make the response only cacheable for 30 seconds.

Similarly, including `readByCurrentUser` will mark the entire response as `private`, so it won't be stored in a public cache.